# Add a checkmark to a toggle switch using HTML and CSS

Tags: css

I can't seem to get a checkmark to display in the toggle. I have the following CSS:

```css
/* CSS for toggle checkbox */

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-checkbox label,
.toggle-checkbox label,
.toggle-checkbox label {
  transition: 400ms all ease-in-out 50ms;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.toggle-checkbox {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  background: rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-out, box-shadow 0.5s ease-out;
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox {
  background: rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
}

.toggle-checkbox label::before {
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.toggle-checkbox label::after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.toggle-checkbox label {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5px;
  left: 2.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox label {
  left: 25px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox label::before {
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 4px);
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox label::after {
  content: '';
  height: 15px;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 7.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<h2>rolling toggle</h2>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<div class="toggle-checkbox">
  <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>
```

I would like to add a checkmark to the switch when it is toggled on.

I have tried adding a checkmark using CSS, but I'm having trouble positioning it correctly. Can someone tell me how to add a checkmark to the toggle switch, and make it displays correctly?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you describe what you want a bit more - what is 'correctly' - where should the mark be?

Comment: What I want is for the check mark to appear as a proper check mark symbol when the toggle switch is clicked. What I'm currently trying to do is make the check mark symbol appear properly, as it currently looks messy even when it's supposed to resemble a check mark. My goal is to achieve a result similar to the following image: https://imgur.com/DLjaofp. I hope this makes it a bit clearer

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this is the result you wanted but I managed to obtain a centered checkmark. I just played around with the position's and rotate's values.

```css
/* CSS for toggle checkbox */

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-checkbox label,
.toggle-checkbox label,
.toggle-checkbox label {
  transition: 400ms all ease-in-out 50ms;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.toggle-checkbox {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  background: rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-out, box-shadow 0.5s ease-out;
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox {
  background: rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
}

.toggle-checkbox label::before {
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.toggle-checkbox label::after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.toggle-checkbox label {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5px;
  left: 2.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox label {
  left: 25px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox label::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50%);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox label::after {
  height: 6px;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(55%);
  left: calc(30%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-40deg);
  background: rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
}
```

```html
<h2>rolling toggle</h2>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<div class="toggle-checkbox">
  <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>
```

I took the liberty of refactoring what you wrote in order to remove redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it had some position-related issue and nothing else ( If I understood your problem though)

```
    #toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox label::after {
        content: '';
        height: 15px;
        width: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 6.5px);
        left: calc(50% - -1px);
        transform: rotate(240deg);
        background: rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #toggle:checked~.toggle-checkbox label::before {
        content: '';
        height: 8px;
        width: 2px;
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 3px);
        left: calc(50% - 6px);
        transform: rotate(159deg);
        background: rgba(73, 168, 68, 1);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```